# Simulating ML-style pattern matching in C++

Tags: c++, pattern-matching

The title says pretty much all, how would I go about simulating ML-style pattern matching in C++, that is for instance;

```
Statement *stm;
match(typeof(stm))
{
    case IfThen: ...
    case IfThenElse: ...
    case While: ...
    ...
}
```

Where 'IfThen', 'IfThenElse' and 'While' are classes which inherit from 'Statement'

Comment: You might be looking for the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: I have considered the visitor pattern, was hoping for something more elegant!

Comment: Judicious use of something like Boost.Variant and tuples can mimic the use of Algebraic Data Types. (Both variants and tuples typically provide ways to deconstruct their values.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There was a paper in the C++ committee recently which describe a library that allow to do just that:

Open and Efﬁcient Type Switch for C++ by Stroustup, Dos Reis and Solodkyy
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3449.pdf

A link to a page with source code :
https://parasol.tamu.edu/~yuriys/pm/

Disclaimer : I didn't try to compile or use this library, but it seem to fit your question.

Here is one of the sample provided by the library :

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include "match.hpp"                // Support for Match statement

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef std::pair<double,double> loc;

// An Algebraic Data Type implemented through inheritance
struct Shape
{
    virtual ~Shape() {}
};

struct Circle : Shape
{
    Circle(const loc& c, const double& r) : center(c), radius(r) {}
    loc    center;
    double radius;
};

struct Square : Shape
{
    Square(const loc& c, const double& s) : upper_left(c), side(s) {}
    loc    upper_left;
    double side;
};

struct Triangle : Shape
{
    Triangle(const loc& a, const loc& b, const loc& c) : first(a), second(b), third(c) {}
    loc first;
    loc second;
    loc third;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc point_within(const Shape* shape)
{
    Match(shape)
    {
       Case(Circle)   return matched->center;
       Case(Square)   return matched->upper_left;
       Case(Triangle) return matched->first;
       Otherwise()    return loc(0,0);
    }
    EndMatch
}

int main()
{
    point_within(new Triangle(loc(0,0),loc(1,0),loc(0,1)));
    point_within(new Square(loc(1,0),1));
    point_within(new Circle(loc(0,0),1));
}
```

This is surprisingly clean !

The internals of the library looks a bit more scary though. I did a quick glance and there seems to be quite a lot of advanced macro and meta-programing.

Comment: In case someone else is looking for the source of Mach7, it's available on github here: https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7

Comment: Note, [it is not thread-safe](https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7/issues/72).